# unable to create a target path for the nuget package in linux , but its working in Windows

Tags: c#, linux, .net-6.0, nuget-package, .net-standard-2.0

currently I am trying to create a nuget package in linux with the help of nuspec file . below is the content of my nuspec file .

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>myProject.Emulation.SPI.Virtual</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>myProject Emulation SPI Virtual</title>
    <authors>myProject AG</authors>
    <owners>myProject AG</owners>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Provides all Emulation .</description>
    <tags>Emulation SPI Virtual</tags>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard2.0" >
        <dependency id="myProject.Energy.Emulation.Loader" version="2.0.1" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" version="2.21.0" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TraceListener" version="2.21.0" />
        <dependency id="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" version="7.0.0" />
        <dependency id="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" version="7.0.2" />
        <dependency id="System.Drawing.Common" version="7.0.0" />
        <dependency id="Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents" version="7.0.0" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="../../_Out/Release/myProject.Energy.Emulation.dll" target="lib/netstandard2.0"/>
    <file src="../../_Out/Release/myProject.Energy.Emulation.Data.dll" target="lib/netstandard2.0"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

by using this command `nuget pack <myproject>.nuspec -version 4.4.4` I am able create a nuget file in linux but when I extract the nuget package in linux I am not able to see the lib folder and the dlls in it .

currently I am using `NuGet Version: 2.8.7.0` in my Ubuntu Linux machine, but the same thing is working in windows where I am able to see the lib folder and its content . In windows `NuGet Version: 6.1.0.106`

please help me on this to fix the issue

below is a example of the nuget pack after extraction in linux

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nuget pack .nuspec -version 4.4.4 -NoDefaultExcludes this command works if we give relative path in src attribute